# Error trying to update plugins

Tags: plugins

I can't update the plugins on a wordpress website, I get this error:

[image]

I also get a 500 error in the console :

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-resizable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-but&load[]=ton,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-dialog,utils,underscore,wp-util,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-ui-progressbar,backbone,wp-pointer&ver=4.8.1:4 POST https://www.hemen-biarritz.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500
```

I checked the files and directories permissions: I have 755 on the dirs and 644 on the files.

I deleted and recreated the wp-content/upgrade dir.

Answer (score 1):

Set the wp-content/upgrade & wp-content/plugin folder permission 777 (Recursive). Once after update the plugins then revert back 775

Comment: ok I'm trying now